# Sci-Fi style TV ad/short film with "magnetic liquid" guy

Tags: story-identification, tv, short-film

Quite a while ago I saw on YouTube (?) a video, where we see from behind a glass a room for focus group/interrogation/group therapy, with several people around a table taking turns and telling their stories, feelings, etc. But when it comes to the last guy, once he starts talking, the "camera" starts glitching as if because of some impulse, the guy becomes more and more frantic, and, to the horror of the others, he starts turning into some different shapes looking like black ferromagnetic liquid with spikes, needles etc., and this spiky blob jumps over the ceiling and the walls keeping to scream incoherently with the guy's voice. I remember some phrases were: "I'm the medium! I'm the message!".

In the end I realised it was kind of an ad for some mobile phone (?) or some big high-tech brand (Philips, Samsung?). I desperately need this visual reference for one project.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_medium_is_the_message?

Comment: @Valorum - It certainly sounds like it's *referencing* McLuhan's statement.

Comment: Welcome to SFF.SE! Can you provide any additional information? In particular: do you remember when you saw the video? I gather that you *think* you saw it on YouTube, but it might have been elsewhere; was it definitely on the internet, or could it have been on television?

Comment: This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: Yes, I definitely saw it on the Internet, several years ago, I believe. I tried to search using these phrases and came up to this McLuhan's thing. And yes, the creators of the ad (?) did this on purpose as it was a part of the creative.  The only other option where I could see it was "The Shots", periodical collection of awarded/cool/rising ads and creative works distributed among ad agencies.

Comment: If it helps, the term for that kind of magnetizable liquid is "ferrofluid."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a Nokia Maemo ad. It's a focus group, and one of the guys in it freaks out and starts glitching like you described while ranting about being the medium and the message. He's called Ash, posssibly alluding to the android that malfunctioned in *Alien*. Here it is:

Comment: That's the one! Fantastic, thanks a lot, mate!

Comment: @user92071 No problem! :) But don't forget to click on the check mark next to the answer to mark this as 'solved'.

Comment: Maybe I'm blind, but I don't see any buttons or checkboxes to do so. (((  A screenshot with a highlighted area might be useful ))

Comment: @user92071 It's the V sign under the answer's score (Also see [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) Meta post)

Comment: Done. )) thanks for the tip and the answer, mate!